# Merge [onkeypress] into [keypress]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I just found that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38485471/1541563) is tagged with [keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keypress) and [onkeypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeypress). According to their tag wikis, 1.7k questions are tagged with [keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keypress), while only 232 questions are tagged with [onkeypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onkeypress).

Can we merge these tags? It seems rather redundant to have both.

Comment: Do we need either of them?  Is there some keypress expert out there that isn't an expert in whatever the question is actually about?

Comment: @davidism It's a user-event that commonly needs debugged. I think it's general enough to keep at least one of them.

Answer (score 6):

`onKeyPress` is the native event handler for JavaScript, whereas `keypress` is part of jQuery's API and also used to indicate the event for a key being pressed in many languages.

I certainly don't think that we need to remove them, because there is some context included with the tag.

I also think that since `keypress` represents such a large group of language agnostic approaches to handling the event for a key press it should probably be the parent of these. Every function in a language's API does not need a tag, and that is probably the case here which is why having both tags is redundant.

As such, I would support merging the tag `onKeyPress` into `keypress`.

Comment: While I agree with your conclusion, some of your points aren't entirely accurate. `onkeypress` (no camel case) is the native _property_ for the JavaScript event. `keypress` is the native event handler name in both native JavaScript (i.e. `.addEventListener("keypress", function(evt) { ... })`) and jQuery (i.e. `$(...).on("keypress", function (evt) { ... })`). Additionally, this is not a tag for a function in a specific language's API, this is a tag that represents the generic user event in any language that interacts with a GUI.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - "The onkeypress property sets and returns the onKeyPress event handler code for the current element." MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress). Note the use of camel case.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - No language other than JavaScript specifically uses the name `onKeyPress` nor `onkeypress` to represent a key press event. So that tag was most likely created for JavaScript and is being misused due to a lack of description in other places. All the more reason to merge them as the `keypress` tag itself does represent a langauge agnostic event (as noted above in my answer).

Comment: Yes I see that `onKeyPress` is in use on MDN, but MDN is not the standard, W3C is. Nowhere in the [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/) does it mention `onKeyPress`, and honestly, it doesn't mention `onkeypress` either, that's exclusively a DOM property as I said, not an event handler. That's the reason I suggested merging it with `keypress`, which is the official name.

Comment: In the [W3C HTML API](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html), it _does_ mention `onkeypress`, but again, not `onKeyPress`.